# DispatchGroup returning multiple times

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, swift3, dispatch-async

Below code which I am using to make `concurrent` API call. somehow this method returning multiple times. I have tested without `DispatchGroup`, It is working as expected. Help me to find why it is calling multiple times.

**My Code Snippet :**

```
     func makeConcurrentCallForUpdating(_ parent: Parent,
                        completionBlock: @escaping (_ success: Bool, _ error: DescriptiveErrorType?) -> Void) 
        let fetchGroup = DispatchGroup()
        let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default)
        let endPoints = [.email, .others ]
        DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: endPoints.count) { (index) in
           let enumType = endPoints[index]
           switch enumType {
           case .email:
               updateEmail(parent, fetchGroup: fetchGroup, completionBlock: completionBlock)
           case .others:
               update(parent, fetchGroup: fetchGroup, completionBlock: completionBlock)
           default:
            break
         }
       } 

        fetchGroup.notify(queue: queue) {
           if self.endPoints.count > 0 {
              completionBlock(false, error)
           } else {
            self.saveUpdated(parent, completionBlock: completionBlock)
         }
        }
   }

   #MARK: EMAIL CALL
       fileprivate func updateEmail(_ parent: Parent,
                             fetchGroup: DispatchGroup,
                             completionBlock: @escaping (_ success: Bool, _ error: DescriptiveErrorType?) -> Void) {
        fetchGroup.enter()
        updateEmail(parent: parent) { (success, error) in
             fetchGroup.leave()
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `enter()` all dispatched tasks before any task in the group will `leave()`.

Move your `fetchGroup.enter()` before `DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(...`

```
    let endPoints = [.email, .others ]
    endPoints.forEach {_ in fetchGroup.enter()} //<- add this line
    DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: endPoints.count) { (index) in
```

And remove `fetchGroup.enter()` in each task:

```
fileprivate func updateEmail(_ parent: Parent,
                         fetchGroup: DispatchGroup,
                         completionBlock: @escaping (_ success: Bool, _ error: DescriptiveErrorType?) -> Void) {
    //fetchGroup.enter() //<- remove this line, in your `update(...)` as well
    updateEmail(parent: parent) { (success, error) in
         fetchGroup.leave()
    }
}
```

Please try.

Comment: This is not working for me. I changed queue in notify method that worked for me " fetchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) " instead of " fetchGroup.notify(queue: queue)". But the loop didn't execute if both .email and .other get called. If I update anyone, its working fine. Any suggestion please

Comment: @venky, thanks for reporting. I'll take some time to investigate further.

Comment: @venky, I have found that my code works as expected, but also have found your original code works. I filled many missing parts by guess, so those parts are affecting, but as you are hiding all of them, I cannot say any more. If you can take some time, please try to make a minimum project which can reproduce your issue, and show all code (not an edited snippet) of it.